# Trouble with python3 datetime

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to convert US date format to EU date format. This is part of an assignment and the instructor has given us a test file to check our answers.

I am able to print the correct date, but I am getting an error on the test.

This is what I have:

```
def US_to_EU(date):
    df = [date]
    f = [datetime.strptime(d, "%m/%d/%y").strftime("%d.%m.%y") for d in df]
    return(f)

US_to_EU('3/13/18')
```

This is what I get when I print the results:

```
['13.03.18']
```

I need it to return:

```
'13.03.18'
```

This is what the test I run is telling me:

```
FAIL: test_US_to_EU (__main__.TestStrings)
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/john/Desktop/John's School/Spring 2019/ISTA 130 Srping 2019/HW/HW 5/test_strings.py", line 12, in test_US_to_EU
self.assertEqual('12.3.18', US_to_EU('3/12/18'))
AssertionError: '12.3.18' != None
```

Can anyone help me with this? I know it is probably the most basic thing ever, but I am 9 weeks new into this right now and still a newb.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of writing:

```
f = [datetime.strptime(d, "%m/%d/%y").strftime("%d.%m.%y") for d in df]
```

you should write:

```
f = [datetime.strptime(d, "%m/%d/%y").strftime("%d.%m.%y") for d in df][0]
```

Or even better, don't wrap the string with an array. So your code will look like this:

```
def US_to_EU(date):
    f = datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%y").strftime("%d.%m.%y")
    return(f)

US_to_EU('3/13/18')
```

This will return `'13.03.18'`.